# How to set a value for a variable using JSON?

Tags: javascript, php, json, dictionary

Distant data I attempt to retrieve with JSON.

```
[{"lat":"42.361730","lon":"-71.131594"}]
```

My javascript code which currently returns error.

```
var pins = $.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
       url: server_url,
       async: false,
       data: { q_type: 6 },
       dataType: 'jsonp',
       jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
       success: function(data) { return data; },
       error: function() { alert('Load error');  }
});
```

My php script

```
echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . '[' . json_encode($new) . ']';
```

Here I know it should be parentheses but if I don't put brackets pins do not load. So I have to find a way to change parentheses by brackets when I send them through json.

Comment: Whats the server url? So we can test it for ourselves

Comment: Also I would suggest setting `contentType: 'application/json'`

Comment: use curved brackets instead of square brackets also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Comment: server_url is the url to my server that I did not disclose here. It links to the php file that sends data to my page.